# how to remove kanban view for all the models in odoo14?

Tags: odoo

I need to remove kanban view in all models like sale, purchase etc. I tried inheriting the kanban view and replace with emptiness. It shows error in inheriting xpath.

Any help is appreciatable!

Comment: try removing it from act window.

Comment: could you please explain it! How could i do it from backend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try by inheriting the action for example:
before:

```
<record id="action_orders" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Sales Orders</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">sale.order</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,kanban,form,calendar,pivot,graph,activity</field>
    <field name="search_view_id" ref="sale_order_view_search_inherit_sale"/>
    <field name="context">{}</field>
    <field name="domain">[('state', 'not in', ('draft', 'sent', 'cancel'))]</field>
    <field name="help" type="html">
        <p class="o_view_nocontent_smiling_face">
            Create a new quotation, the first step of a new sale!
        </p><p>
            Once the quotation is confirmed, it becomes a sales order.<br/> You will be able to create an invoice and collect the payment.
        </p>
    </field>
</record>
```

with inherit you can edit anything what to achive:

```
<record id="sale.action_orders" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Sales Orders</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">sale.order</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form,calendar,pivot,graph,activity</field>
    <field name="search_view_id" ref="sale_order_view_search_inherit_sale"/>
    <field name="context">{}</field>
    <field name="domain">[('state', 'not in', ('draft', 'sent', 'cancel'))]</field>
    <field name="help" type="html">
        <p class="o_view_nocontent_smiling_face">
            Create a new quotation, the first step of a new sale!
        </p><p>
            Once the quotation is confirmed, it becomes a sales order.<br/> You will be able to create an invoice and collect the payment.
        </p>
    </field>
</record>
```

Also i'm not sure if same is possible with fields view get but you can give it a try.

Comment: I did as you insisted and just removed kanban from view mode.

Comment: But i couldn't make it for sale order form

Comment: You can try: <tree editable="top" > in order to edit tree lines but i'm not sure if you're looking for the same.